# Going on a date

Tags: halacha, middos-character-traits, shidduchim-dating

The custom nowadays is that a boy and girl go on *shidduch* dates to see if they are for eachother. Halachically speaking would a boy be allowed to go on a date if he is worried that he will excessively gaze at her and have inappropriate thoughts?

Comment: `What I really mean is, if he is worried that he will excessively gaze at her and have inappropriate thoughts ?` Avoiding dating, and therefore remaining unmarried, will certainly not help the case. In other words: The guy may have a concern that needs to be addressed, but avoiding dates is not the answer.

Answer (score 9):

1) Regarding a *shidduch*, the [*Shulchan Aruch*](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.21.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) says, *"For the sake of marriage, a man may view an unmarried girl or lady to see whether he likes her appearance and general characteristics. It is not only permitted; it is advisable and correct to do so."*

2) If you're worried about inappropriate thoughts, the [*Gemara*](http://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.164b.50?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) states, *"Inappropriate thoughts are one of three things that, on a regular basis, a person is not saved from."*

Still ask your Rav for guidance on how to overcome this issue.

3) Do not avoid going out. For the [*Gemara*](http://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.29b.62?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) tells us, *"One who delays marriage, will each day of his days in sin."* Meaning, an unmarried man will lack the permissible outlet for the passions inherent in man's nature and will come to entertain licentious thoughts regularly.

Comment: `will each day of his days in sin` ?